# Non-homeomorphic manifolds that are homotopy equivalent

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Is there an example for the following?

> Two simply-connected smooth $n$-manifolds which are homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic.

I know the following related results:

- If I remove "simply-connected", then there are lens space examples.
- If I remove "smooth", then there's a non-smoothable 4-manifold homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{CP}^2$.
- If I change "homeomorphic" to "diffeomorphic", then there are exotic spheres.

But I haven't been able to find any actual example after searching for a while.

Comment: Take two rank-2 vector bundles over the 2-dim sphere - if the self-intersection numbers of the zero-section are different,  the total spaces are non-homeomorphic

Comment: @user8268 You should give an official answer.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263060/simple-homotopy-equivalent-non-homeomorphic-manifolds

Comment: @user8268: can you give an explicit example of this? I also don't see why the resulting spaces are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @Hempelicious Every bundle has the same homotopy type as its base.

Comment: @PaulFrost: oh yes of course, I was thinking of the unit bundle, because my.mind was fixed on "compact". I hadn't even considered noncompact examples!

Answer (score 0):

Take the 0 knot traces of two knots (4 manifolds with a 0 framed 2 handle glued along the knot). Then the resulting manifolds $X_0(K)$ and $X_0(K')$ are simply connected (since there is no 1 handle), homotopy equivalent (since all knots are homotopic), but not necessarily homeomorphic (their boundaries are the 0 surgeries of the knots and they are not the same in most cases).