# Two homotopy equivalent closed $n$-manifolds are homeomorphic

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, conjectures

I heard somewhere that there is a wrong conjecture that states:

> Two homotopy equivalent closed $n$-manifolds ($n\geq 3$) are homeomorphic.

and the lens spaces are the first counterexample to this conjecture. I want to know the author of this wrong conjecture, and a reference for it. I am also curious about other counterexamples? ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3505648/272127) is a related question)

Comment: Other counter examples include a famous example of Libgober and Wood that there are two complete intersections in projective space (Example 9.2) here
 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938382900246?via%3Dihub.

These are rather different nature to the Lens space example since the spaces are simply connnected and complex manifolds etc.

I don't know who made the wrong conjecture, but I know that Poincare initially conjecture that spaces with the same $\mathbb{Z}$-homoology are $S^3$ are homeo to it, then disproved his own conjecture inventing homology spheress

Comment: Thank you Nick. I heard the name of owner of this conjecture but I can't write or spell it correctly. His name is something similar to "Horowitz"!!

Comment: Here is a weakening of the conjecture that is true: Let us suppose that the homotopy equivalence of the two manifolds is witnessed by a manifold with boundary in the sense that the two manifolds include disjointly into the boundary of the third, so that each of the two inclusions is a homotopy equivalence. If any of the three manifolds (equivalently if all 3) are simply connected, then the two manifolds we started with are homeomorphic.

Comment: If one removes the simply connected hypothesis this is false and provides many counterexamples to your question, subject to some difficult linear algebra computations (really K-theory). See here for information about both the simply connected and non simply connected case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-cobordism

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there are counterexamples even in dimensions $3$ and $4$. The conjecture fails as soon as it is able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right conjecture (due to Armand Borel, not Horowitz) is that any two homotopy-equivalent closed **aspherical**  manifolds are  homeomorphic, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture). (A manifold is aspherical if it is connected and has contractible universal covering space.) This conjecture is wide-open (in dimensions $\ge 4$) but is expected to be false. The conjecture is known to be true for Riemannian manifolds of negative curvature (very hard work of Farrel and Jones). It is also known to be true for 3-dimensional (aspherical) manifolds, which is primarily due to Perelman's solution of the Geometrization Conjecture.

Comment: Thank you so much. So my spelling of "Horowitz" is correct? Do you know what is his complete name?

Comment: @C.F.G If you are asking about the famous classical pianist, his complete name is Vladimir Horowitz. He has is utterly unrelated to the field of topology.

Comment: No, See this [YouTube lecture](https://youtu.be/BCWBT3OTzNk?t=748) for instance. (don't worry it is about 15 seconds)

Answer (score 3):

I mentioned in the comments one can find families of counterexamples parametrized by a K-theoretic invariant that is normally nontrivial for a nontrivial fundamental group. Computing these invariants is generally difficult. Here is something on the opposite end of the spectrum; something rather easy to produce nontrivial elements of that only works for simply-connected manifolds.

Let $M$ be a simply-connected manifold of dimension $2k-1$ and $2n$ be such that $2k+2n-1>4$. If $Top$ is the colimit of the $Top(n)$, the homeomorphism group of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $G$ is the colimit of the $G(n)$, the monoid of self homotopy equivalences of $S^{n-1}$, then it is a result of surgery theory (dependent on our conditions) that $M \times S^{2n}$ has homotopy equivalences $N \rightarrow M \times S^{2n}$, $N$ a manifold, in bijective correspondence to $[M \times S^{2n}, G/Top]$.

Another very deep result of surgery theory is that $\pi_{4n}(Top/O)=\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_{4n+2}(Top/O)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and trivial otherwise. So if we take the composition $M \times S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n} \rightarrow Top/O$, with the latter a nontrivial map as above, then this gives a nontrivial element of $[M \times S^{2n}, Top/O]$.

So we conclude that at least in every odd dimension greater than four, we have many counterexamples.